# Break the values inside a field and aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed some documents like below

```
{
"height" : "165"
"weight": "102-kgs"
}
```

Now I need to aggregate the weight field,but since it is given as "102-kgs",results in erroneous aggregation. Any way to break and get the weight only?

Comment: The correct way of doing this is to store the unit in a separate field, i.e. `"weight": 102, "weight_unit": "kgs"`

Answer (score 1):

You should be employing scripts for these kind of operations.
In this case the following script would get you the required results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "weights": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weight",
        "script": "_value.split('-')[0]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Any way to convert the weight field into integer?

Comment: you can use the toInteger() method,in Groovy to convert the value to integer.